# Excel slope calculation with offset defined names

Tags: excel

This formula isn't working for me ... can anyone hep?

The data is arranged:
Period cell values ranging from 1-10
The data within EnglandStat is complete and cell values ranging between 1000-2500.

The need for the defined names with offset were so a chart could automatically be updated using two named cells - Shift and Series.

i.e. Series defines that 10 period are displayed on the chart. Shift defines to move the offset range on by 1 data point.

I have two defined names:

```
Period=OFFSET(DATA!$A$13,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B)+0-Shift,0,Series,1)
EnglandStat=OFFSET(DATA!$C$13,COUNTA(DATA!$C:$C)-13-Shift,0,Series,1)
```

I basically want to calculate the slope using:

```
=SLOPE(EnglandStat,Period)
```

I am getting a `#REF` error

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem without a data sample, and knowledge of the definition of the names you have included within the names you have provided.  But sometimes, arrays generated by `OFFSET` need to be enclosed in the `N(...)` function in order to work.  If that is not it, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your original post to provide more information.

Comment: The N() worked ... thanks